# Show MySQL database for user

Tags: mysql

Anyone knows the MySQL syntax to show the database names that a specific user has the privilege to see in a MySQL database? Say the user is 'dimitris' accessing a database at 'localhost', what would be the syntax to see all databases he has the privilege to select, update, insert etc?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For the current logged in user, you can use `SHOW DATABASES;`. But, if the user has the `SHOW DATABASES;` privilege, he'll be able to see all databases, even if he doesn't have access to it. ([reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-databases.html))

Assuming you've read access to the `mysql.db` table, you can use:

```
SELECT * FROM mysql.db WHERE User = 'dimitris';
```

This will return a result set, with `Host` (e.g. `localhost`), `Db` (e.g. `somedatabase`), `User` (e.g. `dimitris`) and the privileges for that database (`Select_priv`, `Update_priv`, etc)

Comment: Thanks. A more complete answer than the accepted one. Voting up.

Answer (score 7):

You can get list of the databases you have access to with:

```
SHOW DATABASES;
```

If you want to get the list for some other user than the user you're logged in as, you have to query the `mysql.db` table.

Comment: Lacks information on what the `mysql.db` query should be. For that reason, I think answer from Lekensteyn is more complete.